# Out of 2 forms, select the one which is in the active div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have 2 forms nested in 2 separate divs like so:

```
<div id="div1" style="display:block">
    <form name="form">
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none">
    <form name="form">
</div>
```

The forms are basically inside tabs so when you switch tabs, the div will become active and so will the form. The other div will change its style attribute to `style="display:none"` and the form will become inactive. Now I'm trying to select the form which is in the active div. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HkRAF/1/)

```
var form = $('div:visible form[name=form]');
```

If you want the form HTML instead of the object:

```
var formHTML = $('<div>').append($('div:visible form[name=form]').html()).html();
```

This is selecting the form that is contained in a visible div, and then getting the forms outer HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much! this is *almost* what I was looking for. I need it to be returned as the form element itself like so: `<form name="form">`. In the existing script its done like so:
`eval('document.theFormName')`;

Comment: You want the form HTML instead of the object?

Comment: yes, i do. I'm modifying an older script and I don't want to screw it up too much. But I just want the FIRST line. so not the stuff that's in between

Comment: @Ortix92 what do you mean by first line? The entire form could feasibly be on one line. Do you want the first line regardless, or just the opening form tag or something?

Comment: The last part kind of destroys the entire form :) Instead of returning an object, I want it to return the first line of the form itself so:
`<form name="formName">`
That's it. Just the first line. Is that possible with jQuery?
document.formName does what I'm talking about

Comment: That doesn't sound right, `document.formName` is the form object, not raw HTML. See edit: fixed the destroy issue.

Comment: Ah excuse me for not being clear; what I meant was just the opening tag indeed. Whenever I run `document.formName` in jsfiddle or in firebug, i get the opening tag of the form..

Comment: `document.formName` is the form object. Maybe you are doing `console.log(document.formName)`, which shows the form HTML, but the console.log call is converting the object to text to output, try doing `typeof document.formName`, see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8YpMY/1/

Comment: I am indeed doing that. I guess that I'm doing something iffy somewhere in my code then! Either way, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) documentation for visible selector.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :visible as MrCode mentioned, but it's also slower than just

```
 var form = $('#div2 > form');
```

so I would do this if in your code you know what div id is active.